# Почему не работает код на мобильном телефоне?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код HTML:

```
<div class="ocf-option-values">
    <label id="v-1987" class="ocf-selected" data-option-id="19" data-filter-label="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ocf[19]" value="" checked="checked" class="ocf-target" autocomplete="off">
        <a href="/postelnoe-belyo/" data-filter-link="" class="current-link">150*220 Полуторное</a>
        <small class="badge"></small>
    </label>
    ...
</div>
```

И JS:

```
$("[data-filter-link]").on("click",function(t){
    t.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("[data-filter-label]").trigger("click");
});
```

На компьютере он работает исправно и все хорошо, но на мобилке он не срабатывает. Я уже и tap пробовал и mousedown, touchstart, touchend, vclick. Ничего не происходит.

Как его заставить работать на мобильном?

Comment: `t.preventDefault(),` почему запятая в конце, а не точка с запятой?

Comment: @Doofy потому что код в одну строчку. Я менял на точку с запятой, это ничего не меняет. Все равно на компе работает, а на мобилке нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-filter-link]', t => {
  t.preventDefault()
  t.target.closest('[data-filter-label]').click()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ocf-option-values">
    <label id="v-1987" class="ocf-selected" data-option-id="19" data-filter-label="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ocf[19]" value="" checked="checked" class="ocf-target" autocomplete="off">
        <a href="/postelnoe-belyo/" data-filter-link="" class="current-link">150*220 Полуторное</a>
        <small class="badge"></small>
    </label>
    ...
</div>
```

попробуй

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое, добрый человек.)